# R column numbers

Tags: r

Have been working with many different datasets lately and need a quick way to identify the column number of different columns.  For example I have a dataset that has 75 variables (or columns).  The variables that I need to use are in the middle of the dataset, I know the names of these variables, i.e. g, h, I, j, and k.  Rather then writing the names of these variables each time I want to use them or change or reference them I usually use the column number i.e.

```
for (i in 35:39) { do bla bla bla}
```

the usual way I find the column number is I look at the data frame and count the columns until I get to the one I want, then I count how many of them there are to get my 35:39.  Is there a better way to do this?  Is there a better way to find out that column/ variable g is column number 35 and column/variable k is # 39?

Comment: I think there are several ways. Here is just an hack: `cbind(1:ncol(iris), names(iris))` it returns a matrix with column 1 equal to the number of the column and column two the name of "n-th" column.

Comment: I like that idea, ill have to give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an expanded version of my comment. As I've said there are several ways to do so, I do not think the right one exist. Here is a possible solution (if I get what you want to achieve of course).

```
 as.data.frame(cbind(column = 1:ncol(iris),names = names(iris)))
  column        names
1      1 Sepal.Length
2      2  Sepal.Width
3      3 Petal.Length
4      4  Petal.Width
5      5      Species
```

In such a way you know what name at which column correspond.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see which column is named `g` you could do

```
which(names(mydataframe) == 'g')
```

which gives you the index of the column with name "g".

Comment: Alternatively, grep("g", names(mydataframe))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` instead of `which` as you need just one column match(which i suppose would be faster as well).

```
match('g',names(mydataframe))
```