# How to subset data frame by column name like SAS in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame x with column names `c("WK1","WK2","WK3",...,"WK100")`, and I want the sum of week 40 to week 60 for each observation.

Now in R I'm using the grep function to find the position of WK40 and WK60 and do the summation:

```
sum(x[i,(grep(WK40,colnames(x)):grep(WK60,colnames(x))])
```

This is fine, but I know in SAS you can just use sum(of WK40-WK60). Is there a better way to do this in R?

Comment: Do you need column sum or just sum of the whole dataset from wk40 to wk60, `select(x, WK40:WK60) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))` is one way with dplyr if you want column sum or `?colSums` after subsetting the dataset

Comment: without a piece of code is hard to help you but have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374963/r-column-numbers/31375044#31375044). You can find the number of the column and then subsetting but just a `c(1,2 etc)`, or c`(1:20)` if you want the first x for example.

Comment: Your description is confusing.  By each observation, did you mean `rowwise` sum ?  In that case `rowSums(x[40:60])` would get the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general base R does not have such a selection operator. The `subset()` function does allows such selections

```
sum(subset(x[i, ], select=WK40:WK60))
```

or to get all row-wise sums at once

```
rowSums(subset(x, select=WK40:WK60))
```

but you can only use literal values (no variables) so it's pretty limited as far as coding against.

You could also use `dplyr` to perform a similar operation

```
x %>% select(b1:b3) %>% rowSums()
```